# Bounded or unbounded for a function $f$ in a metric space.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, functions, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a complete metric space and $f:X\to X$ be a map. Let $\phi: \Bbb R^+ \to \Bbb R$ be any map with $\phi(x)<x$ for all $x\in \Bbb R^+$. Let $\displaystyle P=\frac{d(fx,fy)-\phi(d(x,y))}{d(x,fx)+d(y,fy)}$ for all $x,y\in X$, where $d(x,fx)$ and $d(y,fy)$ NOT both zero simultaneously. .

> I want to find an example of such function $f$ with suitable space $X$ and suitable metric $d$ such that for any function $\phi$, $P$ becomes unbounded.

I have tried by considering various functions and spaces but unable to find such. Please anyone help me to find such. If there is no such $f$ then please give some hint how to prove it?

Comment: @AlexRavsky Actually I mean, $d(x,fx)$ and $d(y,fy)$  not both zero simultaneously. I'm editing it.

Comment: $fy$ should be $f(y).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X=\Bbb N \cup \{n+\tfrac 1{n+1} :n\in\Bbb N\}\subset\Bbb R$ and $d(x,y)=\min\{|x-y|,\tfrac 12\}$ for each $x,y\in\Bbb R$. Let  $f(n)=n+\tfrac 1{n+1}$ and $f\left(n+\tfrac 1{n+1}\right)=n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Then for each map $\phi:\Bbb R^+\to\Bbb R$ such that $\phi\left(\tfrac 12\right)<\tfrac 12$ we have
$$\frac{d(f(n),f(n+1))-\phi(d(n,n+1))}{d(n,f(n))+d(n+1,f(n+1))}=\frac{\tfrac 12-\phi\left(\tfrac 12\right)}{ \tfrac 1n+\tfrac 1{n+1}},$$
so $P$ is unbounded.

Comment: But here, for sufficiently large values of $n$, $d(x_n,fx_n)$ and $d(y_n,fy_n)$ both tends to $0$ simultaneously.

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding..Precisely, I want a map $f$ which has exactly one fixed point with $P$ is unbounded.  Here your function has $4$ fixed points.

Comment: @Topo A map $f$ can even have no fixed points, see the updated answer.

Comment: @Topo - are you saying the condition you want is that $x,y$ must chosen so that $d(x,f(x)) + d(y,f(y))$ is bounded away from zero but that the ratio $$ \frac{d(f(x),f(y)) - \phi(d(x,y))}{d(x,f(x)) + d(y,f(y))} $$ is unbounded?

Comment: @AlexRavsky Actually I am searching a map $f$ with exactly one fixed point in $X$ such that $P$ is unbounded. Yes, here $P$ is unbounded though $f$ has no fixed point. Can it be slightly change so that $f$ has exactly one fixed point with $P4 is unbounded ? I am also trying with this example.

Comment: @AlexRavsky If we include $\{0\}$ with $X$ and define $f(0)=0$ then I think it would be fine with exactly one fixed point. Isn't it ? But in that case, is the space $X$ remains complete with the same metric ? We have to think that also.

Comment: Yes, I think it will be complete trivially, as there are no Cauchy sequence in $X$.

Comment: @Topo All your claims in last three comment are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X=[1,\infty)$ with the usual metric, and let $f(x) = x+1/x.$ Then

$$\frac{|f(x+1)-f(x)|-\phi (|(x+1)-x|)}{|f(x+1)-(x+1)| +|f(x)-x| }$$ $$ =
\frac{|1+1/(x+1) -1/x|- \phi(1) }{1/(x+1) + 1/x}.$$

As $x\to \infty,$ the numerator $\to 1-\phi(1)>0,$ while the denominator $\to 0.$ Thus $P$ is unbounded for any $\phi$ as specified.